# Struts2 iterator tag issue

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

```
<s:iterator value="alist">
    debug: <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
```

I've tried to pass the same list to this iterator on a jsp page twice, and it printed out two different results.

First time,

```
debug: somethingA debug: somethingB debug: somethingC ...
```

Second time,

```
debug: [somethingA, somethingB, somethingC ... ]
```

It gave me the whole list without looping through every single element inside.

What could've gone wrong here?

Note: I have getter and setter for the list in the action class.

Comment: please paste code used at both the spots on your jsp...

Comment: @AndreaLigios hmm what do you mean by no?

Comment: @digidude I only have this one piece of iterator on the jsp. that's why it seems so strange to me. same piece of iterator, same inputs, but different results.

Comment: that is weird. So i assume this is a List<String> that you are working with in this case.

Comment: @digidude not of string but a list of object.

Comment: if its a list of object, you might not want to use <s:property/> like that. use it with value attribute so that the property tag knows on which property to iterate.   for e.g.  <s:property value="fullName" />

Comment: @digidude initially i was doing what you suggested but it's printing out nothing so i decided to do some debugging and then i came to realize that for the second one, it's not even looping thru all the elements but instead treating the whole list as one, therefore it cannot find the "fullName" value of each object inside the list.

Comment: it would be better if you could provide code for your class from which you are building the list and also your action class where you are mapping the values

Comment: With "no" I meant that it's not possible. If the source object is the same, and the JSP code is the same, the result must be the same. You've changed something, or you've different objects in the collection, or you've used different code in JSP.

Comment: @AndreaLigios that's why i asked the question this way, "what COULD have gone wrong?"

Comment: Potentially everything. You need to reproduce the error, and if you can't, it means that probably the error was... you :) meaning that you've committed a mistake without noticing it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.